# What would a good HTTP response to show existence of an entity?

Tags: rest, api, http

I am implementing an API and I want to return an indicator that an entity exists, say for example, it is to check if an order exists in the backend....

```
GET    /order/:order-ref
```

I could return a JSON payload like this:

```
{
  true
}
```

but it seems heavy. I was thinking of just returning a HTTP status to indicate the same. What HTTP status is correct in this case?

Answer (score 3):

> *It seems heavy.*

As [CodeCaster pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58287390/1426227), that's not a valid JSON and I don't see how it can be considered *heavy*.

> *I was thinking of just returning a HTTP status to indicate the same.*

Depending on your needs, you could use the [`HEAD`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) method. It's identical to [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) requests, except that the response will contain only the status line and the headers, without any payload.

```json
HEAD /orders/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

Quoting the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the document that defines the semantics and content of the HTTP/1.1 protocol:

> [**4.3.2.  HEAD**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2)
>
> The `HEAD` method is identical to `GET` except that the server MUST NOT send a message body in the response (i.e., the response terminates at the end of the header section). [...]

> *What HTTP status is correct in this case?*

If the resource exists, return [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1). Otherwise return [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

```json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 8 Oct 2019 13:39:14 GMT
```

```json
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 8 Oct 2019 13:39:14 GMT
```

Comment: This is cool. I was looking for something lightweight and this fits the bill

Answer (score 1):

> but it seems heavy

Apart from it being invalid JSON, are 4 bytes (if you return `true`) or 18 (`{ "exists": true }`) really that "heavy"?

And what if the client wants to see the actual order data, do they need another call?

And what part is exactly "heavy", returning a couple of bytes over an already-open connection, or connecting to and searching your database for determining whether the actual order exists?

But you can return an empty `200 OK`, or a `204 No Content`, if you really want to shave off a few bytes. But I'd recommend against it, see above.

Answer (score 0):

> it seems heavy

It is heavy -- you are trying to denote a single bit (on/off), and to do that you are dragging an entire HTTP Header along with you.  Depending on what tools you are using, you may be able to trim down the header collection, but you are going to be feeling a lot of weight.

> What HTTP status is correct in this case?

There really isn't a great answer.  What you will see done in some cases is to use a 204 to signify that something exists, and a 404 to indicate it doesn't.  That's not the right thing to do; general purpose components do not interpret the status line that way.  But if you control the client, or if you are able to communicate your semantics out of band, then it probably won't be too painful.

The [Github Starring API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#check-if-you-are-starring-a-repository) works this way.

```
GET /user/starred/:owner/:repo
```

That's a resource that exists only when there is a star - its representation is zero bytes long.  If you ask for the representation of a star that doesn't exist, you get an [explanation of the error situation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) that is *also* zero bytes long.

On the other hand, [HEAD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) is "used for obtaining metadata about the selected representation without transferring the representation data."  This is probably closer to your case -- the representation of an order is a potentially large document, but for the client's specific use case only the meta data is necessary.